# Do they still make rear shocks with remote flow control valves?

Tags: shocks

I have a 2007 Stumpjumper FSR frame, I bought the Elite model back in 2006, but it still has the same mounts as the Expert and Pro models for a rear shock with a flow control valve. I haven't been on top of the newest tech trends, so I don't know if flow control valves are obsolete already or not. Have they gone the way of the dodo, or are some bike manufacturers still putting them on their bikes?

[image]

Comment: I must say that *I* haven't clubbed any to death and eaten them. Or was that baby seals? Flow control valves, seals, Dodos, I get confused.

Answer (score 2):

The shock you are referring to was marketed as a 'brain' shock I think. The worked by varying the damping based on detected rear wheel movement. As far as I remember only specialized sold them, first produced for them by Fox and then an in house model. They typically appeared on more XC orientated designs and I've never seen one available as a separate retail product.

Fox have been working on a very similar concept using electronics instead of a remote 'brain' to vary the damping. See http://www.pinkbike.com/news/exclusive-ride-report-fox-live-valve-active-suspension-system.html for more info.